# Aspxscheduler Binding Resources DropDown

Tags: .net, devexpress, scheduler

I have a problem with the Resouces displayed in the aspxscheduler dropdown :
  when i select a program (from the grid in the left), the aspx scheduler is callbacked, the resource is binded in the scheduler but the resource dropdown not visible. when i change the view, the dropdown will be visible.

I think that  the problem is that the dropdown is not binded when the aspxscheduler is callbacked. So how can I access to the dropdown ?

Thanks,

Comment: Show the code which causing problem. It is hard to predict the issue with description without code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This my Client side Code

```
   <dx:ASPxScheduler ID="SchAuditProgram" runat="server" Width="100%" Theme="Aqua" ClientInstanceName="SchAuditProgram" IncrementalFilteringMode="Contains"
                                                        AppointmentDataSourceID="AuditSchedulingDataSource" ResourceDataSourceID="SqlAuditByProgramDS" ActiveViewType="Timeline"
                                                        GroupType="Date" OnCustomCallback="SchAuditProgram_CustomCallback" OnPopupMenuShowing="SchAuditProgram_PopupMenuShowing">
                                                        <OptionsCustomization AllowAppointmentDrag="None" AllowAppointmentDragBetweenResources="None" AllowAppointmentEdit="None"
                                                            AllowInplaceEditor="None" />
                                                        <ResourceNavigator EnableIncreaseDecrease="false" />
                                                        <ClientSideEvents MenuItemClicked="function(s, e) {SchAuditProgram_MenuItemClicked(e);}"
                                                            AppointmentDoubleClick="function(s, e) {SchAuditProgram_AppointmentDoubleClick();}"
                                                            Init="SchAuditProgram_Init" />

                                                        <Storage>
                                                            <Appointments AutoRetrieveId="true">
                                                                <Mappings
                                                                    AppointmentId="ID"
                                                                    Start="BeginDate"
                                                                    End="EndDate"
                                                                    TimeZoneId="(none)"
                                                                    Subject="Description"
                                                                    Type="EventType"
                                                                    Status="Status"
                                                                    ResourceId="AuditID" />

                                                                <%-- <CustomFieldMappings>
                                                        <dx:ASPxAppointmentCustomFieldMapping Name="AuditCode"
                                                            Member="AuditCode" ValueType="String" /> 
                                                    </CustomFieldMappings>--%>
                                                            </Appointments>
                                                            <Resources>

                                                                <Mappings Caption="AuditCode" ResourceId="ID" />
                                                                <CustomFieldMappings>
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="PlannedBeginDate"
                                                                        Member="PlannedBeginDate" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="PlannedEndDate"
                                                                        Member="PlannedEndDate" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="NomSociete"
                                                                        Member="NomSociete" ValueType="Integer" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="Auditors"
                                                                        Member="Auditors" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="Responsible"
                                                                        Member="Responsible" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="AuditCategory"
                                                                        Member="AuditCategory" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="FunctionsAudited"
                                                                        Member="FunctionsAudited" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="ProcessAudit"
                                                                        Member="ProcessAudit" ValueType="String" />
                                                                    <dx:ASPxResourceCustomFieldMapping Name="ProjectName"
                                                                        Member="ProjectName" ValueType="String" />
                                                                </CustomFieldMappings>
                                                            </Resources>

                                                        </Storage>


                                                        <Views>
                                                            <TimelineView IntervalCount="1" ResourcesPerPage="3">
                                                                <Scales>
                                                                    <cc1:TimeScaleYear DisplayName="année" />
                                                                    <cc1:TimeScaleMonth DisplayName="Mois" Enabled="false" />
                                                                    <cc1:TimeScaleQuarter DisplayName="Trimestre" Enabled="false" />
                                                                </Scales>

                                                            </TimelineView>
                                                            <DayView VisibleTime-Start="07:00" VisibleTime-End="19:00" ResourcesPerPage="1">
                                                                <VisibleTime Start="07:00:00" End="19:00:00"></VisibleTime>
                                                                <TimeRulers>
                                                                    <cc1:TimeRuler></cc1:TimeRuler>
                                                                </TimeRulers>
                                                                <Templates>
                                                                    <HorizontalAppointmentTemplate>
                                                                        <div id="cc" class="popUp">
                                                                            <div style="border-bottom: 1px Solid #c0c0c0; text-align: center; font-size: small; font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                                                                                <%# Container.AppointmentViewInfo.Appointment.Subject %>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                            <br />
                                                                            <table style="width: 400px" align="center">

                                                                                <tr>
                                                                                    <td class="label_td4">
                                                                                        <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbBeginDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                                        <%# Container.AppointmentViewInfo.Appointment.Start %>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td class="label_td4">
                                                                                        <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbEndDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                    <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                                        <%# Container.AppointmentViewInfo.Appointment.End %>
                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                </tr>
                                                                            </table>

                                                                        </div>


                                                                    </HorizontalAppointmentTemplate>
                                                                </Templates>
                                                            </DayView>
                                                            <WorkWeekView Enabled="false" VisibleTime-Start="07:00" VisibleTime-End="19:00">
                                                                <VisibleTime Start="07:00:00" End="19:00:00"></VisibleTime>
                                                                <TimeRulers>

                                                         <AppointmentDisplayOptions ShowRecurrence="True"></AppointmentDisplayOptions>
                                                            </MonthView>

                                                            <FullWeekView>
                                                                <TimeRulers>
                                                                    <cc1:TimeRuler></cc1:TimeRuler>
                                                                </TimeRulers>
                                                            </FullWeekView>

                                                        </Views>

                                                        <Templates>
                                                            <VerticalResourceHeaderTemplate>
                                                                <div style="border-bottom: 1px Solid #c0c0c0; text-align: center; font-size: large; font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                                                                    <%# Container.Resource.Caption %>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <br />
                                                                <table style="width: 380px;">

                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbBeginDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%# Container.Resource.CustomFields[0].ToString().Split(' ')[0]%>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbEndDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%# Container.Resource.CustomFields[1].ToString().Split(' ')[0]%>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lblSociete", ressFilePath ) %> : 

                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[2] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("gwIsResponsible", ressFilePath)%> :

                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[4] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("gvwAuditors", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[3] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("tMenuAuditCategory", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[5] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>


                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("TProcessusAudited", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[7] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("hProjet", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[8] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: right" colspan="4">
                                                                            <a href="RequirementNormManagement.ascx">
                                                                                <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("lblSeeMore", ressFilePath)%>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>


                                                                </table>

                                                            </VerticalResourceHeaderTemplate>

                                                            <HorizontalResourceHeaderTemplate>
                                                                <div style="border-bottom: 1px Solid #c0c0c0; text-align: center; font-size: large; font-weight: bold; color: black;">
                                                                    <%# Container.Resource.Caption %>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <br />
                                                                <table style="width: 380px;" align="center" class="TableStyle">

                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbBeginDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%# Container.Resource.CustomFields[0].ToString().Split(' ')[0]%>
                                                                        </td>

                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lbEndDate", ressFilePath ) %> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%# Container.Resource.CustomFields[1].ToString().Split(' ')[0]%>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= IntranetAPI.CommunUtility.getRessourceEntry("lblSociete", ressFilePath ) %> : 

                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[2] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("gwIsResponsible", ressFilePath)%> :

                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[4] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("gvwAuditors", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[3] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("tMenuAuditCategory", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[5] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>


                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td3">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("TProcessusAudited", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[7] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>

                                                                        <td class="label_td2">
                                                                            <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("hProjet", ressFilePath)%> :
                                                                        </td>
                                                                        <td style="font-size: 11px; text-align: left; width: 180px" colspan="3">
                                                                            <%#  Container.Resource.CustomFields[8] %>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>

                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                        <td style="text-align: center" colspan="4">
                                                                            <a href="RequirementNormManagement.ascx">
                                                                                <%= DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("lblSeeMore", ressFilePath)%>
                                                                            </a>
                                                                        </td>
                                                                    </tr>


                                                                </table>
                                                            </HorizontalResourceHeaderTemplate>
                                                        </Templates>



                                                        <OptionsBehavior ShowViewSelector="true" />
                                                        <Storage EnableReminders="false" />
                                                    </dx:ASPxScheduler>
```

This is My Server Side Code

```
  protected void SchAuditProgram_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        if (grdAuditProgram.FocusedRowIndex == -1)
            return;

        var key = grdAuditProgram.GetRowValues(grdAuditProgram.FocusedRowIndex, "AuditProgramID");
        Session["AuditProgramID"] = key.ToString();
        SqlAuditByProgramDS.DataBind();
        SchAuditProgram.DataBind();
        SchAuditProgram.OptionsView.ShowOnlyResourceAppointments = true;
    }
```